# Check if a double is infinite in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a simple calculator for this homework, and Java is returning "Infinity" when divided by 0.

I need to display some error message, when I get infinity. The problem is I don't know how to do the condition

```
double result;
result = 4/0;
//if result == infinity then some message - need help with this
```

Comment: catch [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) check if divisor is zero. show error message.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to get the infinity instead of just stopping the division in the first place?

Comment: aye, deleted my comment, though it's not really mathematically correct

Comment: still, these are two separate problems: handling infinity and handling division by zero (which isn't an error if operands are doubles)

Comment: `4.0/0.0` => `Infinity`, `4/0` is integer arithmetic and it produces an Exception.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `Double.isInfinite(double)`

Here's [double doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

Answer (score 5):

The above code produces

```
ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

You can catch this exception in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 2):

There are two fields for infinity in the `Double` class: `POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` which you can check for.

Note that integer division by zero would throw an `ArithmeticException` thus your line would have to be `4.0/0`, `4/0.0` or `4.0/0.0` since  4 and 0 are integers and thus result in integer math.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if it equal to Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

```
double result;
result = 4.0 / 0.0;
```

Comment: I believe, that's what he doesn't want.  He wants to see an error.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting a super old question because it came up in my Java class. So I'm sure you tried the try/catch like they all suggested, but you found, like me, that it didn't work with `Double`. The try/catch with ArithmeticException doesn't work on `Double` or `Float` since they return "Infinity" instead of returning an exception. (note, delted myold "answer" since it wasn't an answer).

Piecing together a few different questions/answers on this, I came up with the following trials.

```
public class trial
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      double a;
     try {
          a = 4/0;
         System.out.println(" The answer is " +a);
      } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
     System.out.println(" You can't divide by zero. Please try again.");
      }
  }
}
```

The above code should give you the result "The answer is Infinity." At least it did for me since it is a `double`.

With an `int`, it would not need the below `if` statement since it would throw an exception. But since it is a `Double`, the `if` statement below will cause it to throw an exception which the `catch` will... well... catch.

```
public class trial
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      double a;
          try {
        a = 4/0;
   // if statement to throw an AtithmeticException if ans equals infinity
      if(a == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY){
          throw new ArithmeticException();

        }
        else{

          System.out.println(" The answer is " +a);
        }

  } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
     System.out.println(" You can't divide by zero. Please try again.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacek Kwiecień try this code

```
double result;
try{
    result=4.0/0.0;
}catch(ArithmeticException e){

    System.out.println("Math error "+ e.getMessage())
}
```

`

Answer (score -1):

This kind of errors are called exceptions. You can use try-catch block to catch this exception.

```
 try{
      result = 4/0;
 }
 catch(ArithmeticException e){
     System.out.println("You divided by zero");
 }
```

you can read about exception handling [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: Please don't catch generic exceptions if you're just looking for a specialized one.

Comment: Better yet, don't catch exceptions when a simple test would do better.