# how do i fix the illegal start of expression here

Tags: java, calculator, infinity

How do I fix the illegal start of expression here, i don't see anything wrong with it though

```
static void divide(double a, double b){
            double c = (number_a / number_b);
            String s;
            if (c == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || c == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || c == Double.NaN)
                s = "Undefined";
            else
                s = Double.toString(c);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: first check for the denominator

Comment: how do i check the denominator?

Comment: You can either check for `b == 0` or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311604/check-if-a-double-is-infinite-in-java) answer.

Comment: with an if statement, it's not as if you're not using those already.

Comment: how do i implement it though

Comment: i'm new to java programming and i only copied that from one yt video lmao

Comment: you don't learn anything by just copy pasting code. Read a textbook and try and write your own.

Comment: You need to use a conditional statement - and you have 4 of those already in your code. Try to understand what those mean, and work out how to write your own that tests what you need.

Comment: im just trying to change infinity to undefined cuz yes I understood this code

Comment: oh i see, thanks bro, i really appreciate it

Comment: can u help me to change the message infinity to undefined

Comment: ill read a textbook when im college

Comment: `double c = (number_a / number_b)` → `double c = (a / b)`.  Note that the result can be `Infinity` even when `b` is non-zero. (ex. `1e200 / 1e-200`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void divide(double a, double b) {
    double c = a / b;
    String s;
    if (Double.isInfinite(c) || Double.isNaN(c))
        s = "Undefined";
    else
        s = Double.toString(c);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: it says illegal start of expression at 
static void divide(double a, double b)